# Can not solve a relatively easy system of first order PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying

```
DSolve[
 {
  D[f[x, y, z, t], y] z + D[f[x, y, z, t], x] t == 0, 
  D[f[x, y, z, t], t] x + D[f[x, y, z, t], z] y == 0
 }, f, {x, y, z, t}]
```

but it returns unevaluated. Solutions for each of the equations are easily obtained:

```
DSolve[D[f[x,y,z,t], y] z + D[f[x,y,z,t], x] t == 0, f, {x, y, z, t}]
```

returns

```
{{f->Function[{x,y,z,t},Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][y-(x z)/t,z,t]]}}
```

and

```
DSolve[D[f[x,y,z,t], t] x + D[f[x,y,z,t], z] y == 0, f, {x, y, z, t}]
```

returns

```
{{f->Function[{x,y,z,t},Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1][t-(x z)/y,x,y]]}}
```

so presumably it is not that difficult. Actually I know that the answer must be an arbitrary function of $xz-yt$, but I also have a bunch of similar systems to solve. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

Well, since first PDE =0 , and second PDE =0, then PDE1=PDE2, right?

```
pde1 = D[f[x,y,z,t],y] z+D[f[x,y,z,t],x] t;
pde2 = D[f[x,y,z,t],t] x+D[f[x,y,z,t],z] y;
DSolve[ pde1==pde2 , f, {x,y,z,t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried this in Maple 2023.2.1, and Maple does it in reverse! It can solve `[pde1=0,pde2=0]` but can not solve `pde1=pde2`.

```
restart;
pde1 := z*diff(f(x,y,z,t),y)+t*diff(f(x,y,z,t),x);
pde2 := x*diff(f(x,y,z,t),t)+y*diff(f(x,y,z,t),z);
pdsolve([pde1=0,pde2=0]);
```

Gives

[image]

But

```
 pdsolve([pde1=pde2]);
```

Gives no solution.

Comment: Clever! But this is still only another partial answer, as with the separate solutions.